# Split lines separated by tab (or spaces) in a file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tabs, nlp, whitespace

I have a big file (europarl corpus) containing on each line a sentence in English and in German

```
Es gab Tote.    They killed people.
Ich stimme Herrn Mayer in allem zu.     I agree with everything Mr Mayer has said.
```

Above are two example lines. **I just need, for each line, to separate each language sentences**.

As you can see, sentences are separated by a little space (a tab I think ?) consisting of multiple spaces, the problem is that the number of spaces is inconsistent through the file.

Also, sometimes the english version is totally missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a non python solution, in linux shell just:

```
cut -f 1 <name_of_corpus_file>
```

Returns to me exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

Use the `re` package to split each line based off of >1 whitespaces (or a `\t` character):

```py
sentences = re.split('  +|\t', 'Es gab Tote.\tThey killed people.')
# ['Es gab Tote.', 'They killed people.']
sentences = re.split('  +|\t', 'Es gab Tote.   They killed people.')
# ['Es gab Tote.', 'They killed people.']

# Make sure to strip away any additional whitespace
sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in sentences]
```

After splitting it using the above regex, make sure to use the `.strip()` function on each string returned to remove any additional whitespace.

Comment: I should have say it but "." are not on every line or every sentence, I just need to take a line a split in the "middle" where there is a space

Comment: Just edited my answer! Check it out and let me know it if works!

Comment: Your answer is correct for most cases, but some sentences are not split correctly and I still don't know why, I will post my answer which has been given to me using bash commands

Comment: No worries, your Bash solution is simpler & should be quicker too! Best of luck